# Logical socket.io understanding; connections and variables

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

to many this may be an easy question but I'm trying to figure out the reason/logistics as to how socketIO handles variables. In the following code, x is set to 0, every second it counts up. Now if you had 1000 clients connected, every time the connect would each client get a new count starting at 0 and not affect every other connected client?

Also, is there a way to emit a new number to ever connected client instead of each connected client? Thanks!

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    x= 0;
    var socketSend = setInterval(function(){
        x = x+1;
        socket.emit('count', { number: x });
    }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `socketSend` is visible only to inside the callback of `connection` event, so every time a client connects the callback is called, passing along the socket object, so every client will get `0` as a start and the count will begin.

Comment: So what if I had a separate, un-releated process running, say.. monitoring an API, I get some data and I want to push a notice out to all users once I receive the data, can socketIO functions be accessed outside of the "io.sockets.on" function?